# C# - Changing button image event is not rising

Tags: c#, image, events, button

I am making a simple program that changes the image of a button when the user interact with it. When the computer mouse gets inside the button the image highlights, when the mouse clicks it gets darker and when the mouse leaves the button, the image gets norma. To accomplish this behavior I am changing the button image between 3 images, BUT when I click the button and it displays a modal control, e.g. a MessageBox, when it goes back from the MessageBox, the image in the button is still the "mouse inside" image, but the mouse is out of the button already...so I think the button1_MouseLeave event is not rising, but I dont understand why and how to repair it...can you guys help me out on this one?
The code I am using is simple:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace teste1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Botao_Del_Normal));
        }

        private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Botao_Del_Claro));
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test");            
        }

        private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Botao_Del_Clique));
        }

        private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Botao_Del_Claro));
        }        
    } 
}
```

Comment: I think I figured part of the problem...`MouseLeave` is being fired BEFORE `MouseUp` (when the `MessageBox` is called, it fires `MouseLeave`, but when you click the OK button of the `MessageBox` `MouseUp` is called because of the click event)...so even if `MouseLeave` sets the correct image, `MouseUp` will set it back to the "mouse inside the button" image, even if the mouse is out of the button....any ideas how to solve this? `MouseHover` is not a good one, since it takes some time to get fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:
Ok guys, I figured how to make it work! I had to remove the `MouseClick` event, and added all the processing to the `MouseUp` event, so now `MouseLeave` is called after `MouseUp` as it should (even with ALT+TAB).
The code now is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace teste1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Botao_Del_Claro));
        }

        private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Botao_Del_Clique));              
        }

        private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Botao_Del_Normal));
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Botao_Del_Normal));
            // Processing is made here!
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Still the image can blink...any clues how to make it perfect?

Comment: This is for a button that opens some kind of dialog...if it doesnt, so in the `button1_Click` method it should have `button1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Botao_Del_Claro));
`

Answer (score 1):

The mouse sure doesn't leave, because the focus on the button is stolen before that, so it doesn't receive those messages. You should also listen to the LostFocus event and switch to normal image when the button loses focus.

```
private void button1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Image = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.Botao_Del_Normal;
}
```

Make sure to actually listen to the LostFocus event! Just adding the code won't do a thing.

Note that since the signatures of expected LostFocus and MouseLeave delegates are the same, you could actually listen to both events with the same method (and call it something like `button1_MouseLeaveOrLostFocus` or anything that suits you)

Comment: Are you sure there is a `LostFocus` event? I am not fiding it...may be its the `Leave` event?

Comment: Yes, there is a `LostFocus` event. You can also use the `Leave` event, but there is a slight difference between the events - and it is better to stick to `LostFocus` as it is generally better for most cases (I'm pretty sure that `Leave` won't be raised on your button in case your whole form just loses focus). To read more about the difference, click [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/260378-control-leave-vs-control-lostfocus).

Comment: No buddy there is no lost focus event for button control. What .net framwork version are you using?

Comment: @AdeelAhmed It isn't browsable, so you can't see it in the designer, but you can see it in code - which makes me think that I might've mixed the two up - so yeah, OP should probably use the `Leave` event.

Comment: It still doesnt work...when I set it in code as `this.button1.LostFocus += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_LostFocus);` it only gets fired when I ALT+TAB the whole window...and not when the mouse gets out of the button, as was expected...and It doesnt allow me to run it as a MouseEventHandler...and `Leave` also doesnt work...have you guys tried it?
And `MouseUp` is firing after the `LostFocus` so its been a problem too :\

Comment: @mFeinstein Try doing it with the `Leave` event as well - they behave a little different.

Answer (score 1):

Please try button1_MouseHover event instead of button1_MouseEnter Event. 
I will work.

Comment: yes. Posted in anoter answer buddy. Let me know if there is still an issue.

Comment: I kindda worked it out with `MouseClick`, `MouseDown` and `MouseEnter`...I will post the code late this week...I am kinda short of time lately

Answer (score 0):

This is to be expected, as according to your code the image gets reset when you stop clicking, which will be triggered by the window losing focus due to the messageBox.

Delete the MouseUp handler to achieve the behaviour you desire

Comment: The image doesn't get reset when you stop clicking on it, it gets reset (or should get reset) when you don't have the mouse on it. Note that `Claro` and `Normal` isn't the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Text = "Hello World!";
        }

        private void button1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Text = "Mouse Hover";
        }

        private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Text = "Mouse Down";
        }

        private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Text = "Mouse Up";
        }

        private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Text = "Mouse Leave";      
        }      
    }    
}
```

Comment: `MouseHover` is not instantaneous, it takes some time to be considered as been "hovering"